# Sorting a list containing Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have list that contains dictionary that need to be sorted based on the alphabetic order

```
[
    {
        'index': False,
        'definition': {
            'id': 1111111L,
            'value': u'Large Content'
        },
        'id': 1234567L,
        'name': {
            'id': 9999999999L,
            'value': u'INTRODUCTION'
        }
    },
    {
        'index': False,
        'definition': {
            'id': 22222222L,
            'value': u'Large Content'
        },
        'id': 2L,
        'name': {
            'id': 3333333333333l,
            'value': u'Abstract'
        }
    },
    {
        'index': False,
        'definition': {
            'id': 8888888888L,
            'value': u'Large Content'
        },
        'id': 1L,
        'name': {
            'id': 343434343434L,
            'value': u'Bulletin'
        }
    }
    {
        'index': False,
        'definition': {
            'id': 1113311L,
            'value': u'Large Content'
        },
        'id': 333434L,
        'name': {
            'id': 9999999999L,
            'value': u'<b>END</b>'
        }
    },
]
```

I need to sort based on ['name']['value'] to result

```
Abstract
Bulletin
INTRODUCTION
END
```

But when i do it i get the capital letters first

```
bg = []
for n in a:
   bg = sorted(a, key=lambda n: n["name"]["value"])

INTRODUCTION
END
Abstract
Bulletin
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. For the data you have given, I get `[u'<b>END</b>', u'Abstract', u'Bulletin', u'INTRODUCTION']`.

Comment: I remove the html tags using the tip from http://love-python.blogspot.com/2008/07/strip-html-tags-using-python.html

Comment: I just meant that your example doesn't show the problem you were having. In fact, for those four words, case-sensitivity makes no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the sort case insensitive, put everything in lower case in your sort key:

```
bg = sorted(a, key=lambda n: n["name"]["value"].lower())
```

Answer (score 2):

Because capitals are lexicographically smaller. Drop letter case before sorting:

```
key=lambda n: n["name"]["value"].lower()
```